# Syntax error on install

Tags: wordpress, error, install

I installed WP with bitnami on Azure and I am trying to install CIVICRM on top of WP.
My site seems to be working fine but when trying to install civicrm on it right after install I get " Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. 
You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: syntax error
Return to home page."

So I cannot get it working.
When I was using dreamhost for hosting it was working just fine but on here I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Can you find some error messages in log files?  Which version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: latest civicrm. just re-downloaded it 
Which error logs? CiviCRM or the WP error log?

Comment: Error is Dec 21 08:28:27  [info] Creating canary table

Dec 21 08:29:12  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping
FROM   civicrm_option_value v,
       civicrm_option_group g

That's the beginning of it.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your original post and include the full error message